# IE 9 Tab Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, internet-explorer, controls

How can we use the Tab Control that Internet Explorer 9 uses in our Windows Forms applications? And is it OK to use it? Is there a DLL somewhere that we need to download, or choose from within the Toolbox?

Or are there any samples, tutorials or articles around somewhere that demonstrate how to change the look of the old Tab Control in WinForms?

Comment: These links might help you: [CodeProject: Creating a IE9-like UI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110614/Creating-a-IE9-like-UI.aspx) and [rudigrobler.net: Creating a IE9-like UI](http://www.rudigrobler.net/creating-a-ie9-like-ui).

Comment: Hmm, those are some great links. I think they will definitely help me in the right direction; Good starting point. :) - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, no, you can't use the IE9 tab control; it's custom UI specific to IE and it is not exported in any public manner.  You can try to imitate it, as others have pointed out.